# certificate issue GCP with GoDaddy

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, certificate

I have an issue with my website's certificate. The domain is from GoDaddy, website is hosted on App Engine GCP (certificate managed by Google). Sometimes when people are trying to access a website it says that 'Connection is not private' (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).
Furthermore when users press the details about the website it says that Certificate is not valid, but when certificate's details are pressed it shows that the certificate is valid.

I'm using yes-https (js to redirect http to https).

What could be the reason of this problem?

Error:

[image]

GCP:

[image: GCP]

GoDaddy:

[image]

Update:

The last DNS updates (on GoDaddy) took place yesterday, and we started using this domain last week (we have two different domains running the same code).

After simple refresh, certificate changes to:

[image]

Comment: Starfield is not a Google certificate authority. They are part of GoDaddy. Did you recently change your DNS server settings? It could be that some clients are getting your old site and some are getting your new site. Edit your question with details on the history and timeframe of any changes.

Comment: DNS changes are not instant. DNS is cached by servers around the world. Plan on 24 to 72 hours for changes to take place.